# Problem with mod_wsgi: Getting a permission denied

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi, httpd.conf

Hello I seem to be getting an error when restarting my httpd.conf file for apache. I have tried to reinstall python, but that has not made any difference.
Recently, I had to do a clean installation on my server so I'm pretty much reinstalling and configuring everything.

```
`Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 200 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so: cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied`
```

In my httpd.conf file at line 200, I have

`LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so`

Comment: 1. What dist are you using? 2. Have you installed mod_wsgi? 3. Have you checked the file permissions on mod_wsgi.so so that apache can read the file?

Comment: 1. Not sure what you mean 2. Yes , 3. It has permissions of -rwxr-xr-x 1 which should be fine. Oh - I am using a Red Hat server as well.

Comment: Alright. By dist I meant Linux distribution. So this happened when you restarted apache?

Comment: @Ancide: Bacically what I have written up. `cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied`

Comment: @Shehzad009 I didn't mean WHAT I meant WHEN this happened. You wrote "restarting my httpd.conf" and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Ancide: I see, well I had to reinstalled my server because there where some problems with the home directory being corrupted. So I had to install everything again. This included the latest version of python, django, wsgi etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in the mod_wsgi documentation at:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Secure_Variants_Of_UNIX

Comment: Still need some help. In my security level configurations. SELinux setting is disabled. I have tried reinstalling python but still get that same error.

Comment: They say it is better to put it into permissive mode. See http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html You will need to have restarted Apache. Worst case reboot your box.

Comment: This worked out well actually. I actually incorrectly SELinux disabled. But It works from here `crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html`.Changed it back to enforcing after.